# One Signal Push Notification Using Expo in React Native

Tags: react-native

> Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNOneSignal.setAppId')]

that error occurs everytime. what i do now? it works on React-native-cli Project. it gives error on Expo-cli

```
import * as React from "react";
import Home from "./Home"
import OneSignal from "react-native-onesignal";

class App extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    /* O N E S I G N A L   S E T U P */
    OneSignal.setAppId("bb92b317-9038-4a4c-a52a-e0f3f9b3f163");
    // OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);
    OneSignal.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(false);
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse(response => {
      this.OSLog("Prompt response:", response);
    });

    /* O N E S I G N A L  H A N D L E R S */
    OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(notifReceivedEvent => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal: notification will show in foreground:", notifReceivedEvent);
      let notif = notifReceivedEvent.getNotification();

      const button1 = {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => { notifReceivedEvent.complete(); },
        style: "cancel"
      };

      const button2 = { text: "Complete", onPress: () => { notifReceivedEvent.complete(notif); } };

      Alert.alert("Complete notification?", "Test", [button1, button2], { cancelable: true });
    });
    OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(notification => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal: notification opened:", notification);
    });
    OneSignal.setInAppMessageClickHandler(event => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal IAM clicked:", event);
    });
    OneSignal.addEmailSubscriptionObserver((event) => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal: email subscription changed: ", event);
    });
    OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(event => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal: subscription changed:", event);
      this.setState({ isSubscribed: event.to.isSubscribed })
    });
    OneSignal.addPermissionObserver(event => {
      this.OSLog("OneSignal: permission changed:", event);
    });

    const deviceState = await OneSignal.getDeviceState();

    this.setState({
      isSubscribed: deviceState.isSubscribed
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Home />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Can you share a solution?